# c# Windows App Form - Graphics dementions not adding up

Tags: c#

I set my "panel" to 200, 200 and used the Graphics function to draw 4 boxes.  Each box is 50x50 pixels and starts at the lower right corner of the last box.
It looks like stairs I guess.
If the form is 200, 200 it should mean that the boxes extend from the top left of the form to the lower right, but that is not the case.  Only 2 1/2 boxes show inside the form.  It is like the boxes have different size pixels than the form.
Thank you for the help

```
 private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gObject = canvas.CreateGraphics();

        Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Pen redpen = new Pen(red, 10);

        gObject.FillRectangle(red, 0, 0, 50, 50);
        gObject.FillRectangle(red, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        gObject.FillRectangle(red, 100, 100, 50, 50);
        gObject.FillRectangle(red, 150, 150, 50, 50);
        }
```

Comment: Obvious debug step: do each box in a different color so you can see which one is which...

Comment: The box that does not show is the bottom right.  You can see the two top boxes and the corner of the 3rd box.

Comment: Check the actual panel size.  You sure it's 200x200?

Comment: Ya, I am sure about the pixels of the panel.  I also am having problems with sizing in other places on my form.  I am going to my school tomorrow and am going to cut and paste my code into one of their computers.  I am wondering if it is something to do with windows 10 / computer settings.  Thanks for your interest in this

Comment: "dementions" -> "dimensions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.
In windows 10 you can adjust the display in the settings(I had mine adjusted because the graphics are very small on the monitor).  Windows itself recommends you set it 150% not 100%.
This will distort the graphics in Visual Studio.

Solution is to set Windows 10 display to 100% not the default 150%